# Unable to pass array to method in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

So I have this function.

```
array = Array.new

def put_array(array)
  l = array.index(array[-1])
  puts l
  for i in 0...l do
    puts array[i]
  end
end

put_array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

the output is to print the array but I keep getting this result.......

```
 5
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

**Error** ::The index output is 5, whereas the expected output should be 6.  I have tried rindex,array.last instead of array[-1] but I keep getting same answer

Comment: What did you expect the answer to be?

Comment: We don't know the output. This output seems perfectly reasonable given your code. What do you want to do/get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your expected output was.

But your error comes from the fact that array indexing in ruby is zero-based, ie they start at 0. Therefore :

- Despite your array having 6 elements, the index of its last element is 5.
- This also mean that when you start iterating through your array with an index value of 1, you are starting with its second element.
- On a different note, with `1...l` you are defining an exclusive range, that is a range of integers from 1 to l, excluding `l`. If you want to include l, you need to use `1..l`

A quickfix to your code would be :

```
for i in 0..l do
 puts array[i]
end
```

But a more idiomatic way of achieving the same output would be :

```
array.each {|e| puts e}
```

Also

```
l = array.index(array[-1])
```

looks a bit convoluted. Why not simply ?

```
l = array.length
```

Comment: I was wrong , I mistook index to be length.....I wanted to print length so array.length did the job for me

Answer (score 0):

If you simply `puts` **array** it will print each element of array in new line:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
puts array
#=> Output:
1
2
3
4
5
6

def put_array(array)
  puts array
end

> put_array(array)
```

If you want to perform on index basis:

```
> array.each_with_index {|e,i| puts array[i]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused because `0...5` outputs the number range 0,1,2,3,4 and not 0,1,2,3,4,5. You need to use `..` rather than `...` at the line starting `for i in`

```
def put_array(array)
  l = array.index(array[-1])
  puts l
  for i in 0..l do
    puts array[i]
  end
end

put_array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

That will output:

```
 5
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```

Though as others have stated, there are easier ways to achieve the same output.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are trying to print the array, if it so .. your code can be modified this way

```
array = Array.new

def put_array(array)
  l = array.length
  for i in 0...l do
    puts array[i]
  end
end

put_array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

[index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-index) gives you the index for the given object, so in your case `index(-1)` will give `nil` because the array does not contain `-1`.

Instead you want to do this:

```
array.index(6) # => 5 (6 is at index 5 of array)
array[5]       # => 6 (5th item in array is 6)    
array[-1]      # => 6 (-1th (aka last) item in the array is 6)
array.last     # => 6 (last item in array is 6)
```